# How to derive this fastest-mixing Markov chain?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, projection-matrices

I am studying the fastest-mixing Markov chain in Stephen Boyd & Lieven Vandenberghe's *Convex Optimization*, but I am stuck trying to understand the following derivation.

---

[image: fastest mixing Markov chain problem to find P]

---

How does it calculate the following spectral norm?

$$\| Q P Q \|_2 = \left\| P - \frac 1n 11^\top \right\|_2$$

Can someone put a glance and clear it to me. Will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
r &= ||QPQ||\\
&= ||(I -(1/n)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T)P(I -(1/n)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T)|| & \text{// definition}\\
&= ||(I -(1/n)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T)(P -(1/n)(P\mathbf{1})\mathbf{1}^T)||\\
&= ||(I -(1/n)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T)(P -(1/n)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T)|| & \text{// } P\mathbf{1} =\mathbf{1} \\
&= ||(P -(1/n)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^TP -(1/n)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T+(1/n^2)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T|| & \text{// Distrib}\\
&= ||(P -(1/n)\mathbf{1}(P^T\mathbf{1})^T -(1/n)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T+(1/n)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T|| & \text{// } \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{1} = n\\
&= ||(P -(1/n)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T -(1/n)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T+(1/n)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T|| & \text{// } P=P^T,\quad P\mathbf{1}=\mathbf{1}\\
&= ||(P -(1/n)\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T|| \\
\end{align*}$$